# Increase values from vector for each call

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, c++14

I want to use a function for a vector multiple times and for each call to increment the vector's value. How could I do it ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A
{   
    void pri(std::vector<int>& a)
    {
        std::cout<<"0: " << a[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout<<"1: " << a[1] << std::endl;
    }
    
    void priUse(std::vector<int> a)
    {
        pri(a);
        int x = 12;
        **pri(a + 12);** // to work this
    }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a = {1, 2};
    A aa;
    aa.priUse(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "increment the vector's value". Do you want to increase the vector size?

Comment: Before you continue read this : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/passing-arguments-by-reference/. You're working on copies of the vector not the original one

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think vector are passed by reference, just like the arrays. But anyways, KereanStones you just need a for loop

Comment: what "`std::vector` + `int`" suppose to do?

Comment: I think maybe you want a different kind of 'vector' than `std::vector`; have you seen [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)? Maybe it's more like the 'vector' you had in mind, in which case there are multiple suitable 3rd party libraries to choose from (i.e. you probably don't actually want to use valarray).

Comment: this was rhetorical question showing that you are expecting here something fishy. Some would expect adding element at the end, others add value to last element or evens something completely different.

Comment: @Enrico No not for priUse that's passed by value.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to note here is that

1. you need a loop to iterate through each element of the `vector`.
2. We have to pass the vector **by reference**.

##### Solution

If you want to write a function that increase all elements of a vector by 1 that you can use the following approach:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    void pri(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        //iterate through the vector and increment each element's value 
        for(int &element: vec)
        {
            ++element;
        }
    }
    void priUse(std::vector<int> &vec)
    {
        pri(vec);
    }
    
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a  = {1,4,6};
    std::cout<<"before incrementing: "<<std::endl;
    for(const int& element: a)
    {
        std::cout<<element<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    
    //create object 
    A aa;
    
    //call the member function 
    aa.priUse(a);
    
    std::cout<<"after incrementing: "<<std::endl;
    for(const int& element: a)
    {
        std::cout<<element<<" ";
    }
    
}
```

##### Output

The output of the program is:

```
before incrementing: 
1 4 6
after incrementing: 
2 5 7
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Pass the vector by reference.
2. Subscript operator returns a reference to the element of the vector that is just modifiable (if you are not working on a const vector). E.g. `a[0]++` will increment the value of the vector's first element.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/rMeh6ezP4)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

struct A
{   
    void pri(std::vector<int>& a)
    {
        std::cout << "0: " << a[0]++ << "\n";
        std::cout << "1: " << a[1]++ << "\n";
    }
    
    void priUse(std::vector<int>& a)
    {
        pri(a);
        std::cout << "After first call to pri(a); ...\n";
        pri(a);
        std::cout << "After second call to pri(a); ...\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2};
    A aa;
    aa.priUse(a);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   0: 1
//   1: 2
//   After first call to pri(a); ...
//   0: 2
//   1: 3
//   After second call to pri(a); ...
```

If you want to update the elements of the vector by adding a variable amount to them, pass that amount as a parameter, then walk the vector getting a reference to each element (e.g. with a range based for loop), `auto& i : a`, and update that reference:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/KGhdPYWah)

```cpp
    void pri(std::vector<int>& a, int val)
    {
        std::cout << "0: " << a[0] << "\n";
        std::cout << "1: " << a[1] << "\n";
        
        for (auto& i : a) { i += val; }
    }
    
    void priUse(std::vector<int>& a)
    {
        int x{12};

        pri(a, x);
        std::cout << "After first call to pri(a); ...\n";
        pri(a, x);
        std::cout << "After second call to pri(a); ...\n";
    }

// Outputs
//
//   0: 1
//   1: 2
//   After first call to pri(a); ...
//   0: 13
//   1: 14
//   After second call to pri(a); ...
```